# University campus map Navigation in Augmented Reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want to create an app in Augmented reality how to achieve below requirement 
1.Wayfinding in 3D directions
2.Scanning the University structures and getting the info

Reference Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgRdutPZNug

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for this, If yes, then give some link.